# Ruta proyectos recientes android studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenos dias, tenia android studio 2.2 y cuando abría el menú de proyectos recientes la ruta de los mismo me salian en la parte de arriba. Asi como muesto en [image: Imagen] , ahora cuando estoy en el menu de recientes muestra la ruta abajo y como la ruta es muy larga. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi como muestro en esta imagen y no logro distinguir un proyecto de otro. 
¿Existe alguna manera de configurar esto?
Saludos y gracias por su respuestas

Comment: Arriba solo aparece la ruta del proyecto actual, al menos por defecto. En el menú desplegable de `Open recent` existe la opción (debajo del todo) de `Manage projects...`. Ahí aparecerá los proyectos recientes con su correspondiente ruta y podrás visualizarlo mejor, tal vez.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, pero esa opcion de Manage projects no me sirve, la ruta de mis proyectos es larga por lo general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al parecer no existe una forma de configurar esto, pero ver la ruta de tu proyecto tal vez no es tan útil como además poder abrirlo directamente en finder o explorer, mediante la secuencia:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

puedes ver la ruta de tu proyecto o directorio del proyecto y además acceder al mismo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Como dice Jorgesys no existe forma de configuar esto lo unico que pude hacer fue administrar los proyectos recientes eliminar muchos que tenia como muestro en la imagen 
[image: Administrar recientes]

pudeo ver la ruta cuando estoy en el menu de recientes pero en la parte de abajo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]